# Authorization code flow with Azure B2C, Angular and client backend

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, authorization, azure-ad-b2c

I want to create an authorization code flow similar to the screenshot below. I have an Angular app, deployed alongside a .NET Core client backend and using Azure B2C as an authorization server. Unfortunately I'm not quite sure how the flow goes.
I have a login button in my Angular app, does this directly call the Azure B2C with a redirect to the client backend? Or does the login button link to the client backend and this redirects to Azure B2C? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you are wondering what endpoint is the Angular App calling on button click.  This depends on your implementation of the Http call in your Angular app.  You would have the login button call a service to Login.  That service will  inject the HttpClient in the constructor.  Then, in the login method on the service, you will use the httpClient to create your API call which will include the URL of the endpoint you want to call.  If you call your client backend, you can call the Azure B2C endpoint and handle the authorization there and pass either a 200 or 401 status code back to the Angular app.  If you want to call your Azure B2C directly from Angular, you would handle the response accordingly based on what Azure B2C will return (I have not used Azure B2C previously so I do not know the response that the API will return).  I hope this helps.  Below I have a link to the Angular docs regarding the HttpClient.

[Angular Docs on Http](https://angular.io/guide/http)